# Measure estimated completion time of ruby script

Tags: ruby

I've been running a lot of scripts lately that iterate over 10k - 300k objects, and I'm thinking of writing some code that estimates the completion time of the script (they take 20-180 minutes). I've got to imagine though that there's something out there that does this already. Is there?

To Clarify (edit):

Were I to write code to do this, it would work by measuring how long it takes to perform "the operation" on a single object, multiplying that amount of time by the number of objects left, and adding it to the current time.

Granted, this would only work in situations where you have a script involving a single loop that takes up 99% of the script's total run time, and in which you could reasonably expect to be able to calculate an semi-accurate average for each iteration of that loop. This is true of the scripts for which I'd like estimate completion time.

Comment: I think you need to have some kind of "base time of execution" that you can extrapolate from.
I'd say something like: execute a 100 or 1000 times iterations over a small representative subset, measure the average execution time, and start from this to extrapolate how much time it would take for every future execution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at the `ruby-progressbar` gem: https://github.com/jfelchner/ruby-progressbar

It generates a nice progressbar and estimates completion time (ETA):

```
example task:     67% |oooooooooooooooooooooo         | ETA:  00:01:15
```

Comment: This looks like what I want, though it is unclear to me is how it will  work in a situation where the code that's running is generating a lot of output. Will try implementing this and accept if it its a good fit. Thanks!

Comment: Does not work that well if your script also produces output into the console. But I think you should write output into a logfile (or pipe STDERR into an file) anyway.

Comment: This library is really well done and can be customized extensively. Definitely the way to go. Take a look at this formatting for processing a large number of records: `ProgressBar.create( format: "%a |%b>>%i| %p%% %c/%C %e", total: total )`

Answer (score 1):

You can granularity measure the time of each method within your script and then sum the components as described [here](http://www.skorks.com/2010/03/timing-ruby-code-it-is-easy-with-benchmark/).

Answer (score 1):

You let your process run, and after a set time of iterations, you measure the elapsed time. You then use that value as an estimation for the time left. This ensures that the time is always dynamically estimated according to the current task.

This example is extra verbose, like a code double whopper with triple cheese:

```rb
# Some variables for this test
    iterations = 1000
    probe_at   = (iterations * 0.1).to_i
    time_total = 0
#======================================

iterations.times do |i|

    time_start = Time.now

    #you could yield here if this were a function

    5000.times do # <tedius task simulation>
        Math.sqrt(rand(200000))
    end # <end of tedious task simulation>

    time_total += time_taken = Time.now - time_start

    if i == probe_at
        iteration_cost = (time_total / probe_at)
        time_left = iteration_cost * (iterations - probe_at)
        puts "Time taken (ACTUAL): #{time_total} | iteration: #{i}"
        puts "Time left (ESTIMATE): #{time_left} | iteration: #{i}"
        puts "Estimated total: #{time_total + time_left} | iteration: #{i}"
    end

    if i == 999
        puts "Time taken (ACTUAL): #{time_total} | iteration: #{i}"
    end
end
```

You could easily rewrite this into a class or a method.